# How include a feynmp file in beamer title page?

Tags: beamer, feynmf

How does one include a diagram done with feynmp in a beamer title page? feynmp produdes .1 files but when I include them as graphics, the labels of the different lines/vertices do not appear on title page. **Can one directly generate feynmp diagrams on the title page of a beamer presentation?**

Comment: No example? You should know, by now, that a MWE is needed.

Comment: Is that always the case? :( I'm afraid to give up too much info that's why I never include it. But OK I guess rules are rules.

Comment: @LoveLearning: providing a MWE has nothing to do with disclosing "too much info".

Comment: @LoveLearning Just use a generic theme and a generic diagram; there are so many variables that trying to guess what you want is almost impossible.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, well the best way would be to copy what I have including all the packages I use etc and then paste it here (with some clean-up of course that could take e.g. half-an-hour) but this always introduces the potential of pasting stuff one might regret later. Sometimes (most of the times) the question is so simple (in the sense of asking: how does one write a bold italic maths symbol) that I find it an exaggeration to include MWE. In any case rules are rules I guess.

Comment: @egreg OK I'll do that from now on.

Comment: @LoveLearning I believe that `\documentclass{beamer}\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` should be as good as a full featured preamble, for the problem at hand.

Comment: @LoveLearning: don't take it as "rules are rules" :) Providing a MWE just helps how wants to answer you to not create everything from scratch (i.e, `\documentclass`+ blablabla + example of diagram). As you save their time, likely you'll get a faster answer ;)